# How does my code work without loc or iloc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is from an exercise in DataQuest. Dataset can be found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/1uyd0t/200000_jeopardy_questions_in_a_json_file

I have a function that basically finds out how many times a word in the answer comes up in the question in jeopardy.

```
def AnsFromQ(row):
    split_answer = row['clean_answer'].split(" ")
    split_question = row['clean_question'].split(" ")
    match_count = 0
    if 'the' in split_answer:
        split_answer.remove("the")
    if len(split_answer) == 0:
        return 0
    for word in split_answer:
        if word in split_question:
            match_count += 1
    return match_count / len(split_answer)

jeopardy['answer_in_question'] = jeopardy.apply(AnsFromQ, axis=1)
```

My question pertains to lines 2 and 3 using `row['clean_answer']`. How does python know that I want to refer to a cell (intersect of a row and column) without using something like `jeopardy.loc[row,['clean_answer']]`? I could have used any variable for `row`.

This code works. I just don't know why. If I use the code with `loc`, it gives me a warning in jupyter saying I need to use `reindex()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `jeopardy.apply(AnsFromQ, axis=1)`, you are applying the `AnsFromQ` function to each row of the Dataframe.  The `row` variable gives you a slice of the dataframe representing the current row.  In order to use `jeopardy.loc[row,['clean_answer']]`, `row` would need to be a value from `jeopardy`'s Index.

In other words, `row` is a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) that gives you a view of each row.  Indexing into that with `row['clean_answer']` gives you the cell from that column index in the current row.